# How to convert this string to SimpleDateFormat "dd-MM-yyyy"?

Tags: java, jcalendar

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MM dd, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date;
date = parser.parse(date1);
output = formatter.format(date);
```

date 1 is "Sunday, March 3, 2013"

Comment: Have you read SimpleDateFormat's javadoc?

Comment: nope but now i have, and it works now "EEEE, MMMMM d, yyyy" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
```

`EEE` is for the day of the week and `MMM` is for month in the long format.

You should take a look at the documentation of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: No. MMM is for the month name in abbreviated format. And EEE is for the day name in abbreviated format.